# Simple inter-proccess communication in Qt4

Tags: qt, qt4, operating-system, desktop

I need to make so that my application can have only one instance running at a time. Also when it's launched with a command line parameter ( like when registered to open certain file types ) it should pass the parameter to an existing instance and quit immediately without displaying graphical interface. You all probably know what I mean. The framework used is Qt 4, and it seems like it must have some facilities for that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a Qt Solutions project doing this:

[Qt Single Application](http://www.qtsoftware.com/products/appdev/add-on-products/catalog/4/Utilities/qtsingleapplication/)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do inter process communication. Examples can be found in Qt's [examples section](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/examples.html#inter-process-communication).

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to implement a this sort of class oneself using QSharedMemory
(see QSharedMemory::attach() ). It's capable of being used for both determining whether other instance is already running and communicating/sending messages. Except some pointer magic and memory copying it's quite straightforward.